# iOS - AudioSession Cateogry for AudioUnit Application

Tags: ios, ios5, core-audio, audio-streaming, audiounit

I am working on streaming audio player application for iOS. currently i am experimenting with **AudioQueue** and **AudioUnit** for playback.

Both works fine in the normal condition. But I am facing an issue with AudioUnit version of app when it goes to sleep mode.

**AudioUnit** version of the application stopped the playback when application goes to sleep mode. Where as **AudioQueue** version of the application playing with out any issue during the sleep mode.

I have set **"kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback"** session category for both cases. I assume this session category should continue the playback even in sleep mode.

I am not sure what i am missing here.

I want to add pan/effects features to my application, so i am trying with AudioUnit.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have got the AudioUnit Implementation working.  I have set the AudioSession category as "kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback". As i am using AudioUnit for playback, i need to set "kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice" property to 4096. so it will continue the playback even in the device is in the sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's documentation on audio sessions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategories/AudioSessionCategories.html), you should probably use `kAudioSessionCategory_SoloAmbientSound` instead. This will stop all sounds from other applications, but that's the price you pay for being able to keep playing when the device is locked.

Comment: Let me try with your suggestion. but when i use **"kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback"** with AudioQueue,it worked fine even the device is in sleep/standby.but it did stop playing when i use it with AudioUnit.